# Why Firefox does not show pictures of my web?

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have an issue with web I am developing HTML/CSS (only design), if I open it in firefox from my harddrive no pictures are displayed, there is a small icon instead like picture can not be loaded. If I rightclick on a icon and select open picture in new tab than picture is displayed on a new tab without issue.

But if I open webpage from my hardrive in IE, edge or chrome than all pictures are displayed directly on a page in a browser without issuel.

What can be wrong with mozilla or with page?

I tried all these recomended fixes: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/fix-problems-images-not-show.
this is picture URL: img src="D:/UserData/z003xner/Documents/My Web Sites/bubabikes/Images/30.1.2023.jpg" and i tried forward slash and bacward shash and nothing helps

Answer (score 2):

Try to put the image inside the project folder for eg : **{project_path}/images/1.jpg** and call the image using the domain name in the project suppose the project domain is https://example.com call the image using

```
<img src="https://example.com/images/1.jpg" class="image" />
```

or if in localhost :

```
<img src="http://localhost/project-name/images/1.jpg" class="image" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s hard to tell, but the issue may be the spaces in your file path — try replacing them in your html with `%20` like this

```
my/file%20path%20has/spaces.jpg
```

You can look up “url encoding” for more information!